# Random from float grouping MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of bids and I want to select a random value. But I want to group that by the bid amount.

```
+--------+------------+
| bid_id | bid_amount |
+--------+------------+
|      1 | 0.00002    |
|      2 | 0.00002    |
|      3 | 0.00001    |
|      4 | 0.00002    |
|      5 | 0.00001    |
|      6 | 0.00002    |
+--------+------------+
```

So for example, I want to select a random value, where the bid_amount is 0.00002. Here's my query:

```
SELECT bid_id FROM bids 
WHERE bid_amount = ? 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

But for some reason it doesn't seem to work. It seems like there is something weird going on with floats in mysql where I can't seem to match them properly in the condition.

Is there some way I could do this using `GROUP BY bid_amount` and then select the first or second rows using `LIMIT 1` or `LIMIT 1,1`?

**So in other words, select a random value from a GROUP BY?**

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: When I type 0.00001 in as the where value in as a manual query it works. But when I use php it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with floating point values.  One solution is to use decimals.  Otherwise, try something like:

```
SELECT bid_id
FROM bids 
WHERE ABS(bid_amount - ?) < 0.0000001
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: How would I convert a column to be decimal then for 5 decimal places? Is there a query I could run to do that?

Comment: @AmyNeville . . . You would define it as something like `decimal(10, 5)`.